# spring.job.enabled: true causing junit jobs to run twice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring boot spring batch project. The following setting is in my application.yml

```
# Spring Framework Standard Properties
spring:
  batch:
    job.enabled: true
```

When I have this setting set to true as above it causes my junit tests to run twice everytime I kick off a unit test.

When I change the setting to false my junit tests run once when I kick off the same unit test.

A couple of questions...

I am not 100% clear on what this setting is. Can someone tell me more.

And also is there anything I can put in my unit test to change this to false just for my unit tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the official documentation:](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.html)

> By default a Runner will be created and all jobs in the context will be executed on startup.
>
> Disable this behavior with ***spring.batch.job.enabled=false***.

Comment: Thank you! Is there something I can put in the unit test ( like setting this via an annotation) to override what is in the application.yml file?

Comment: You can create application-test.yml in `src/test/resources` and put it in there and just annotate your class with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`. Or just annotate your class with `@IntegrationTest("spring.batch.job.enabled=false")`, it will override the property for that test.

Comment: @IntegrationTest("spring.batch.job.enabled=false") worked!. This is the solution that suits me better bc I don't want to have to redefine everything that is in my other application.yml file.

Comment: Actually, you would just have to put the overrides into application-test file. But yeah, either should work so whatever fits better for your use case.